# Creating an exe file with pyqt5 gui

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller

My main goal is to create a onefile of my project and I'm having trouble in creating an executable file with pyqt5, I'm using pyinstaller. When I create a onefile it does not work, here 's how I do it

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed main.py
```

And when I dont use onefile(this is just my second option but I really need to produce a onefile) I still run in an error but I fix this by  way of copying some .dll to pyqt bin in dist folder and all other python files together same with my .ui files and images. Is there a way to not do this copying files?

Comment: Show the steps you follow in both cases, in addition to the complete error messages. On the other hand it seems that the second method works (not onefile) What is the problem with the second method? I recommend you read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pyinstaller —-onefile —-windowed —-noconsle main.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you get an empty folder where you are supposed to get your file?

I am fairly new to pyinstaller, but I was having a similar issue. My antivirus was deleting the .exe that I compiled, thus making it seem as if nothing happened. Try making an exception with your antivirus to where your exe should be created.